# Connection refused when I try to connect my pc to raspberry pi via internet bridge

Tags: connection

Hi guys I'm trying to connect the raspberry pi to a pc via internet bridge.
I have a rj45 port free (eth0): so I've set these settings:

```
Ipv4 Settings: Method Shared with other computers
Ipv6 Settings: Method Ignore
Ethernet: Mac address I have choose the eth0 mac address
```

After that I connect the raspberry pi to the pc via rj45 cable. I wait until the led are switched on. Then via shell I type this command

```
sudo nmap -sP 10.42.0.2-254
```

Where 10.42.0.x is the lan of my pc.
When I find the raspberry pi' ip I'm tryng to connect via  xtightvncviewer I'm getting this error:

```
 xtightvncviewer: ConnectToTcpAddr: connect: Connection refused
 Unable to connect to VNC server
```

But if I try to connect via Putty it works perfectly.
Someone could explain what problem can cause this issue?
Greets

Comment: What is this internet bridge?  Does it need ports to be opened for VNC?

Comment: For internet bridge I mean to connect pc and raspberry physical port via rj45 cable

Comment: I'm not familiar with VNC.  Do you have a VNC server running on the Pi?  What port does it use?